# erb:how to filter on resource attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I filter the results based on the resource attribute in .erb file. For example, I would like to display product which price is lower than 50 dollars. The following is current .erb file. The price tag is a string, need to be converted to number.

```
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= product.title %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= product.count %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Can I use this in the view? I have undefined method "filter" error.

```
       <% @products.filter { |p| p.price < 50 }.each %>
       <tr>
       <td><%= product.title %></td>
       <td><%= product.price %></td>
       <td><%= product.count %></td>
       </tr>
       <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: you can either use `select` to only select products with a price less than 50 dollars or even `partition` to split the list into those below and above that price.
Ideally you'd do this outside of the view, though, for example inside your controller or even the model.

Basic filtering (inside view):

```
@products.select { |p| p.price < 50 }.each do |product|
```

Or with a scope in the model:

```
scope :below_price, ->(price) { where("price < ?", price) }
```

You can use it in the controller:

```
PRICE_THRESHOLD = 50

def index
  @products = Product.below_price(PRICE_THRESHOLD)
end
```

Comment: This is my first rails project. Do you mean I can do the following in the view?

Comment: <% @products.filter { |p| p.count > 30 }.each %> <tr>
                                <td><%= product.title %></td>
                                <td><%= product.price %></td>
                               <td><%= product.count %></td>
 
                                </tr>
                           <% end %>

Comment: Sorry, I was just doing some JS code and mixing up the method names XD - In Ruby, the method is of course called `select`, not `filter`

Comment: And of course you still need to append the `do |param|` like you were already doing. Fixed my answer...

Comment: comparison of String with 200 failed:    <% @products.select {|p| p.price > 200 }.each do |product|%>

Comment: How can I convert the princ(string) to a number here?

Comment: Problem sovled with to_i. Here is the statement:<% @products.select {|p| p.price.to_i > 200 }.each do |product|%>

Comment: So your `price` attribute is a string? You might want to create a migration to convert the `price` column to a decimal field then.

Comment: Now I have all the lower priced product. How can I accept the parameter so that I can have all the product or all the lower priced product?